# "Build succeeded" but "The breakpoint will not currently be hit"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, dosbox

I am working against [DOSBox-X](https://github.com/joncampbell123/dosbox-x) project code base.

Most of the time breakpoints do work but sometimes I will get  `The breakpoint will not currently be hit` even though the build succeeded. This most likely happens when tiny changes are done to the code (few characters) or simply switching back to main branch after a merge (no changes at all).

Of course, if I rebuild the whole project or execute `Build full program database for solution` it will invariably work but it takes quite a couple of minutes for the former, a bit less for the latter but still significant time.

TL;DR; it happens randomly

Can some expert shed some light on what could be causing this?

Comment: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit even though the build succeeded." - Why do you expect any relation between those two things? If the build succeeded, good. The build may have optimized out the code where your breakpoint is, also good - the compilers optimizer did its job well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by resetting most project properties to default values, debugging now works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Whether your build succeeded doesn't have very much to do with whether breakpoints work, except that if you don't have a successfully-created executable then there's nothing to debug.

When you change your source code, it is no longer "in sync" with the code that was used to create the executable. That doesn't inherently mean the executable is no longer debuggable (it still has symbols and such like, after all), but Visual Studio is a graphical IDE, whose debugger is integrated into the source code editor.

If it doesn't have that source code any more, that integration is not going to work properly, and that includes the breakpoints that you set on line *X*. What is line *X* now? It disables them, as a result, to avoid confusion.

Just make sure you're debugging the program as it *currently* stands, per the source.

*(Note: it does get stuck sometimes. I've occasionally had to do a Clean All to get breakpoints to start working again, even though I hadn't changed any code. But this should be a very rare occurence.)*

Comment: Obviously both are not in sync anymore, causing this issue, but I am looking for a more practical answer than a theoretical one :)

Comment: @Aybe: It _is_ a practical answer.